# Convert ASP.NET Button to HTML button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I would like my button in asp convert to html button.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="EditCustomer" CommandName="UpdateRow" ToolTip="Accept Changes" ImageUrl="~/Web/Images/accept-40x40.png" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
case "UpdateRow":

            UpdateCustomer();
            FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
            DisplayCustomer((int)FormView1.DataKey.Value);
            break;
        }
    }
```

My html button is not working now..

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" title="Edit" ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" onserverclick="UpdateRow">
```

Comment: `CommandName` and `onserverclick` are not the same. You cannot copy the commandname for an ItemCommand to a html button like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the event's implementation, when you use the attribute "OnServerClick" you must specify the event, no the CommandName, so you need to add an event like this to your code:

```
protected void UpdateRow(object Source, EventArgs e) {
    UpdateCustomer();
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
    ...
}
```

If you want to use the button using the property CommandName, you can't use an HtmlButton.